# Create directory with Cordova FileWriter

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I want to safe a file in a new directory with PhoneGap and filewriter.
I have this code:

```
fileName = fileSystem.root.fullPath+"/test.html";
var writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
writer.write("ttteeeesssttttt", false);
```

With this I can create the test.html file and it works.
But when I change the path to:

```
 fileName = fileSystem.root.fullPath+"/test/test.html";
```

it doesn't work....

is there a simple way to solve this problem or should i create the directory first in an other function?

thank you! :)

Comment: You need to explictly create the directory before you can create a file within it

Answer (score 3):

Check this when onDocumentReady fired:

```
    function CreateFolder(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, creatingFolder,       error);
   }
```

This create the folder:

```
 function creatingFolder(fileSystem) {
    var entry = fileSystem.root;
    entry.getDirectory("test", {create: true, exclusive: false}, win, error);
}


 function win(dir) {
  console.log("Created dir "+dir.name);
  console.log("Created dir "+dir.fullPath);
  console.log("Created dir NativePath" + dir.nativeURL);
}
```